# Rails best practices with multiple update forms for one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, crud

I have a general question about model updating that I guess relates to a larger question of how to organize models and controller actions in the most 'Rails-y' way possible. I have multiple update forms for a given model `Profile` (and it’s associations). For example, one form might be for updating basic information like `first_name`, `last_name` and another might be for updating things like `age`, `jobs` etc. In my case, there’s like 8 of these different forms and they're a bit more complex then the examples I'm giving. I’m wondering about the trade-offs between different ways of handling this setup. In the past I've tried 3 different ways:

1)  Having custom controller actions (in the Profiles controller) to handle each of these different update forms. Ex.

```
#views
<%= simple_form_for @profile, url: profile_update_name_path(@profile), method: :patch, remote: true  do |f| %>
    # the form fields
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for @profile, url: profile_update_basics_path(@profile), method: :patch, remote: true  do |f| %>
    # other form fields
<% end %>


#profiles controller
def update_name
  if @profile.update
    # do some stuff
  end
end

def update_basics
  if @profile.update
    # do some different stuff
  end
end
```

2)  Passing in an extra param as part of the form’s url in order to differentiate responses to the forms. Ex.

```
#views
<%= simple_form_for @profile, url: profile_path(update_form: “name-form”), method: :patch, remote: true  do |f| %>
    # the form fields
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for @profile, url: profile_path(update_form: “basics-form”), method: :patch, remote: true  do |f| %>
    # the form fields
<% end %>


#profiles controller
def update
  if params[:update_form] == "name-form"
    if @profile.update
      # do some stuff
    else
      # handle errors
    end
  elsif params[:update_form] == "basics-form"
    if @profile.update
      # do some different stuff
    else
      # handle different errors
    end
  end
end
```

3)   Breaking the model up into separate smaller classes that are all somehow connected to the parent model Profile model via has_one, belongs_to relationships. Ex.

```
#profile.rb
has_one :name_information, dependent: :destroy
has_one :basic_information, dependent: :destroy
has_many :jobs, through: :basic_information

#name_information.rb
# has attributes: first_name, last_name
belongs_to :profile, touch: true

#basic_information.rb
# has attributes: age
belongs_to :profile, touch: true
has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs, allow_destroy: true

#views
# each form now points to the update action for it's own controller rather than using the profiles_controller
<%= simple_form_for [@profile, @name_information], url: profile_name_information_path(@profile, @name_information), method: :patch, remote: true  do |f| %>
    # the form fields
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for [@profile, @name_information], url: profile_name_information_path(@profile, @name_information), method: :patch, remote: true  do |f| %>
    # the form fields
<% end %>
```

I’ve had some success using all of these techniques but in all honesty, I’m not sure that any of them are great practice. Does anyone have any thoughts on what the best “Rails” way to handle this kind of setup would be? The third option of breaking things up into smaller classes seems like it might be best to me, but it is also less appealing for a larger application where changing these base models will have major repercussions throughout the entire app. It also makes me wonder about the efficiency of loading a bunch of smaller associated objects that could easily be part of one class.

Comment: I'm voting to close, because this is a **VERY** opinion-based question. There is no definitive right/wrong answer even for a *specific* situation, let alone the general case. My answer is: Whatever woks best for you. It depends.

Comment: However, I do think it's worth mentioning an option 4: What if you just have a single `update` action, with whitelisted attributes for updating, and each form just sends a subset of those attributes? A `patch` request doesn't need to be a *full* set of parameters; but only the ones you *want* to change.

Comment: @TomLord I agree. I'm somewhat new to answering on StackOverflow, but added an answer anyway. Is this type of question generally a bad one to answer here?

Comment: @DerekHopper Questions like this are usually closed as opinion-based, but I think your answer is about the best you could have given in this situation. I tend to avoid answering such questions, but I think your response here has value!

Comment: @TomLord fair enough. I realized it would probably a bit borderline in terms of having a "right answer". But I thought there would still be something to be added in terms of where one course of action might be better than another. Also with respect to your option 4, I do need to somehow at least determine which form is being submitted since the actual ajax response for each form will be slightly different.

Comment: @Brett for a "monolithic" application such as yours, this may be true. (But not always!) However, if your rails app only responds with json (as most modern, complex apps do!) then it's far more likely that you'd just return a serialised profile record in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is there are a bunch of different opinions on this. Some people might say throw everything in one model and one controller and be done with it. However, I think you're right to be thinking about the future when you say:

> The third option of breaking things up into smaller classes seems like it might be best to me, but it is also less appealing for a larger application where changing these base models will have major repercussions throughout the entire app.

I have one more question you could ask yourself:

- Will these forms have different sets of validations?
- Which approach would be easier to debug if you have issues?

If they do and you only have one model, you may find yourself fighting with a big set of conditional validations. It may become unclear which validations run when.

Personally, an approach with a combination of 1 and 3 seems nice. There are benefits you would get out of the box.

- Each form would have its own route and permitted params. This is helpful if you need to know which forms are being filled out. You'd also be able to disallow the first_name from being updated on the basic information form.
- Having multiple controller actions seems like it would be easier to understand 3 years down the road. The downside is it might be easy to duplicate a lot of things if you're not careful.
- Debugging could be easier when you have multiple controller actions. If someone is having troubles, you might be able to clearly identify the form they're using without much effort.

**Possible Solution**

There's a pattern I like which is similar to what you described in your 3rd idea. You would keep your `Profile` model, but use a form object for each form. The form object would store validations specific to each form. Each controller action would use a different form object to process the request.

Basically, the `Profile` model would only be changed through one of the form objects.

Here's an example:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class BasicInformation
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :age
  validates :age, presence: true
end

def ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action do
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update_name
    name_params = params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
    if NameInformation.new(name_params).valid?
      update_profile(name_params)
    end
  end

  def update_basic_information
    basic_information_params = params.require(:profile).permit(:age)
    if BasicInformation.new(basic_information_params).valid?
      update_profile(name_params)
    end
  end

  private

  def update_profile(params)
    @profile.update(params)
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if I'd use this exact way, but hopefully the main idea is clear. It's also not the only way to do things. Like I said, people are going to have differing opinions on this. It really depends on the amount of complexity you need to handle.

Keeping everything in one model and one controller might work perfectly fine for you.

If you're looking to read more into form objects, I've seen a bunch of different ways to handle form objects over the years. Here's a list:

- https://thoughtbot.com/blog/activemodel-form-objects
- https://github.com/trailblazer/reform
- https://web.archive.org/web/20160926183428/https://webuild.envato.com/blog/creating-form-objects-with-activemodel-and-virtus/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I agree with the user above that this definitely has value. Using form objects is a totally new pattern to me so I'm taking a look now. Just to be clear it looks like a form object would not (can not?) be backed by a corresponding table in the database? That object would just be used to subsequently pass data into my Profile object that is connected to the database?

Comment: @Brett Correct. It would delegate to your `ActiveRecord` object for persisting the data. A form object is a way to decouple complex form submissions from your model. It helps when you have a bunch of logic for one form, but you don't need/want that logic polluting the underlying model. Keep in mind it could be overkill for your situation though. You'd have to make that determination.